# Find percentage in non zero columns

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in R

```
    ID     IT      FMCG     CDGS
    A       0       20       50
    B       10      30       67
    C       23      0        40
```

I want percentage share of non zero columns and print in new column. e.g FMCG (20/(20+50)) 28%

Desired R dataframe

```
   ID      IT     FMCG    CDGS         Perc_Portfolio
   A        0      20      50        FMCG(28%),CDGS(72%)
   B       10      30      67       IT(10%),FMCG(28%),CDGS(62%) 
   C       23      0       40         IT(36%),CDGS(64%)
```

and so on, I am using following code to print the non zero column names

```
simplyfy2array(apply(df[2:4],1,function(x)paste(names(df[2:4])[x!=0],collapse="")))
```

How to add percentage in above code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` to loop over the rows, subset the elements that are not 0, divide the by `sum` of elements to create the percentage and `paste` with the `names`

```
df1$perc <- apply(df1[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) {
            x1 <- x[x!=0]
            if(length(x1)==0) {
            ""} else {

          x2 <- round(100*x1/sum(x1))
          paste0(paste(names(x2), paste0(x2, "%"), sep="(", collapse="), "), ")")}})
df1$perc
#[1] "FMCG(29%), CDGS(71%)"         "IT(9%), FMCG(28%), CDGS(63%)" "IT(37%), CDGS(63%)"
```

Comment: Why are you not including the "%"? Also, even though correct, I feel like the way you are using paste here might make it a bit difficult to understand. Maybe using `paste0(names(x2), "(", x2, "%)", collapse=", ")` is easier to understand

Comment: @akrun Thanks alot,just one question. If there are blank rows it still prints `(%)` how can I avoid that to be printed?

Comment: @Neil Did you meant `NA` elements in your data.  In that case, we need to do `x1 <- x[x!=0 & !is.na(x)];` in the second line.  Or if it is `""` then `x1 <- x[x!=0 & x!=""]`

Comment: Not NA, when there are all zeros in a row,it prints `(%)`

Comment: @Neil Okay, In that case, what do you want to print there?

Comment: Nothing simply blank `""`

Comment: @akrun Its giving me an error. `object 'x1' not found`

Comment: @Neil I am not getting the same error with this data

Comment: @Neil I think I got what you meant.  Updated the post

Comment: @akrun Thanks.Now its working perfect. appreciated. You alwayz help me :)

Answer (score 3):

Another idea using `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 gather(val, var, -ID) %>% 
 filter(var != 0) %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 summarise(new = toString(paste0(val, '(', round(100*var/sum(var)), "%", ')')))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
#     ID                          new
#  <chr>                        <chr>
#1     A         FMCG(29%), CDGS(71%)
#2     B IT(9%), FMCG(28%), CDGS(63%)
#3     C           IT(37%), CDGS(63%)
```

Comment: Thanks alot. appreciated